# Custom pagination using react-table

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to customize the pagination as Previous 1 2 .... N-1 N Next which is as : 
[image]

And I m using react-table version 7. I referred to their example and was not able to achieve it. I want this pagination to be dynamic based on the data input.Can someone please help me to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Is this worked for you https://codesandbox.io/s/012ywx6mp0?file=/src/Pagination.js

Comment: NO, it didn't! Can u suggest me something else, please ???

Comment: your picture and given example are same I think. so why it didn't ?

Comment: Maybe becoz of the version , Sir I tried that it is not working :( Can u please suggest me something else ?

Comment: If it is not working in your side then probable reason should be the version I believe. Here I used the version of `react-table` is `6.8.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the Pagination given by antd (https://ant.design/components/pagination/) and now got the output as required.
                                                                                             [image]

This worked for me.